# Show unselected option in dropdown and selected option in dropdown head in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have a bootstrap dropdown select option where i have only two options. I want to show one option as a selected one and other option in dropdown list which is unselected. That is, dropdown list will always show the unselected option. Below is my code.

```
<div class="select_list" ng-class='{active:active}' ng-click="active=!active">
    <span ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+obj.language_selected.url+')'}">@*{{obj.language_selected.name}}*@</span>
    <ul class="options">
        <li class="select_list_option"
            ng-repeat="language in language_list"
            ng-click="obj.language_selected=language"
            ng-style="{'background-image':'url('+language.url+')'}">\
          {{language.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code :

```
$scope.obj = { language_selected: { 'name': 'USA', 'url': '/Content/Images/us.png' } };
$scope.language_list = [{ 'name': 'USA', 'url': '/Content/Images/us.png' },
                        { 'name': 'UK', 'url': '/Content/Images/uk.png' }
                       ];
```

Attaching the image for reference:

[image: dropdown flag]